# PHP while loops and if statement issues when pulling from multiple tables

Tags: php, ms-access

I have 2 tables with a unique ID. I have a table with one of the columns being a date field. I am attempting to filter the field by today's date (which it works) from all the rows with "todays" date I want to get the cell info for #key. Once I have that ID, I want to match it with #headkey. So $headkey == $key. Once I filter that, I want to see if any of the fields match = Delivery for the ItemID column. For some reason I have an infinite loop. I played around with the logic but can't seem to get it to work. Any ideas?

```
 $TransactionSql = "SELECT * FROM apcshead WHERE DateInvoiced > 0 ORDER BY DateInvoiced DESC";
 $ItemsSql = "SELECT * FROM apcsitem";

 $rs=odbc_exec($conn,$TransactionSql);
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs)) 
{   
    //Grabbing Transaction info     
    $DateInvoiced = odbc_result($rs,"DateInvoiced");
    $ApcsheadKey = odbc_result($rs,"Key");

    $DateInvoiced = new DateTime($DateInvoiced);
    $DateInvoiced_date = $DateInvoiced->format('m-d-Y');
    //$TimeStamp_time = $TimeStamp->format('h:i:s');

    if ($DateInvoiced_date == $today)
        {

            $ItemsRs=odbc_exec($conn,$ItemsSql);
            while($row = odbc_fetch_array($ItemsRs)) 
            {
            $HeadKey = odbc_result($ItemsRs,"HeadKey");
            $ItemID = odbc_result($ItemsRs,"ItemID");

            if ($ItemID == 'Delivery')
                {                       
                    echo 'Delivery';
                    echo '<br />';
                }
            }
        }
}
```

**UPDATE:**I modified the code again. Now what if does is it spits out 1 row with the date and then like 100 echo Delivery and then goes back and spits out another date and the same thing. Still not sure what is going on.

```
 $TransactionSql = "SELECT * FROM apcshead WHERE DateInvoiced > 0 ORDER BY DateInvoiced DESC";
 $ItemsSql = "SELECT * FROM apcsitem";

 $rs=odbc_exec($conn,$TransactionSql);
    while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs)) 
{   
$DateInvoiced = odbc_result($rs,"DateInvoiced");
$DateInvoiced = new DateTime($DateInvoiced);
$DateInvoiced_date = $DateInvoiced->format('m-d-Y');

 echo $DateInvoiced_date;
 echo '<br />';

if ($DateInvoiced_date == $Today)
    {
    echo $DateInvoiced_date;
    echo '<br />';

        $ItemsRs=odbc_exec($conn,$ItemsSql);
        while($row = odbc_fetch_array($ItemsRs)) 
        {
        $ItemID = odbc_result($ItemsRs,"ItemID");

            if ($ItemID == 'Delivery')
                {
                echo 'Delivery';                
                }  
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: positive it's an infinite loop and not just a long running task?

Comment: @Zarathuztra - Yes. If I remove anything that is currently in the IF statement for $DateInvoiced_date == $today and just echo out $DateInvoiced_date I get no more than 20 rows. So technically I should only be getting 20 echos with 'Delivery'

Comment: cool, thanks for the info. Investigating

Comment: @Zarathuztra - Thank You. All I can pinpoint is that something within that loop I screwed up, but can't seem to know what it is

Comment: I noticed you're creating rows but not using them. Have you tried that? Doubt it would cause your loop, just a bit of housecleaning.

Comment: @Zarathuztra - The 2 rows I am currently not using are ApcsheadKey and  ItemID. I want to use them within instead of the echo 'Delivery'. I have not tried implementing them. Was trying step by step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue using the INNER JOIN command. It is great because I don't have to do nested loops :)
Learned how to do it from W3Schools. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

This is my current SQL Statement:

```
 $TransactionSql = "SELECT apcshead.Key, apcshead.DateInvoiced, apcshead.InvNum, apcsitem.Headkey, apcsitem.ItemID FROM apcshead INNER JOIN apcsitem ON apcshead.Key=apcsitem.Headkey";
```